# Unordered output from bufio.Scanner

Tags: go, cmd

I use golang to receive mtr info and after some work send it to `os.stdout` 
However the output is in unordered.
the code below

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        input := scanner.Text()
        fmt.Println(input)
    }
```

The right order looks like this

**image description here**

[image]

And this is the output from the code above:

**image description here**

[image]

Comment: We can't tell what the actual text is from pictures of your screen. Have you compared the raw bytes input vs output? How is the output generated in the terminal (line by line, or possibly via a curses library), and how do you get it into your program?

Answer (score 1):

The `mtr` program is using special terminal escape sequences to redrawn the lines it has written. It's output is **not** in order.

That is why you fail.

Comment: is there anyway to achive the same result？ thinks

Comment: @LiumChen: Many ways. You could just modify the source code of mtr to do what you need it to do. Or use traceroute instead. Or find out if mtr uses a library that you could also use, or if you could convert the mtr code into a library.

Comment: @LiumChen: Or possibly you could read the mtr manual and see that it has command-line options designed to produce reports.

Comment: but if you use python print，then all is ok

Comment: while 1:
 try:
  line = sys.stdin.readline()
  if not line:
   break
  print  line
 except:
  sys.exit() ## python code like this ,everython goes fine

Comment: @LiumChen: No, the python code produces mixed up output also. Did you try it? I did, just now.